# How to draw a 2D graph on Canvas in Unity 5

Tags: c#, graph, unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

I need to draw a graph for my decibel app that I am making with Unity. The solution below works but is not as exact as my employer would like. Could I make this graph look more professional and exact? Basically I want the lines to be of equal width and prevent the line from going almost invisible like in the following pic: http://puu.sh/qjSvO/a51c11cef5.png

I was thinking about making a 2D texture and using SetPixel, but I am not sure if that is the correct way.

The graph is drawn on a canvas as part of an scalable UI.

```
 public class Graph : MonoBehaviour {

 public float graphWidth;
 public float graphHeight;
 LineRenderer newLineRenderer;
 List<int> decibels;
 int vertexAmount = 50;
 float xInterval;

     GameObject parentCanvas;

     // Use this for initialization
     void Start ()
     {
         parentCanvas = GameObject.Find("Canvas");
         graphWidth = transform.Find("Linerenderer").GetComponent<RectTransform>().rect.width;
         graphHeight = transform.Find("Linerenderer").GetComponent<RectTransform>().rect.height;
         newLineRenderer = GetComponentInChildren<LineRenderer>();
         newLineRenderer.SetVertexCount(vertexAmount);

         xInterval = graphWidth / vertexAmount;
     }

     //Display 1 minute of data or as much as there is.
     public void Draw(List<int> decibels)
     {
         if (decibels.Count == 0)
             return;

         float x = 0;

         for (int i = 0; i < vertexAmount && i < decibels.Count; i++)
         {
             int _index = decibels.Count - i - 1;

             float y = decibels[_index] * (graphHeight/130); //(Divide grapheight with the maximum value of decibels.
             x = i * xInterval;

             newLineRenderer.SetPosition(i, new Vector3(x - graphWidth / 2 , y - graphHeight / 2 , 0));
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: It looks like you may have accidentally set either `widthCurve` or `colorGradiant` - possibly in the inspector instead of in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Using the editor, you can "cut" sprites into nine pieces, so that there is a texture for each side, a texture for each corner and a texture to fill it in. I would recommend using that to make it look good if you want it so. It is some time since i used it myself, but maybe you can find information on the Unity manual.

Comment: I tried screing around with the sprite editor but could not get much help out of it. Basically I want to prevent the line width from changing like in this picture: http://puu.sh/qjSvO/a51c11cef5.png

Comment: Then I misunderstood you. I thought it was a pillar graph, if you understand.